# How to resolve unrecognized selector sent to instance in master-detail application?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I'm create new master-detail application in Xcode 7.
Then I'm create new view controller for start application. But when I'm started application the IDE sent this to me :

```
[UIViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe49a53c0b0
```

I'm try comment this code in app delegate file can start app normally:

```
//    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
//    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
//    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
//    splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

But this case can't stared app :

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
//    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
//    splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

How to resolve this problem? Thanks for help guys.
 
Sorry for my english is not very good.

Comment: have you check class object created perfectly or not. may be you are not creating objective in right way that why you get that error

Comment: Check if your splitViewController is not nil or maybe you have something else in self.window.rootViewController ?

Comment: Oh @ConstantinSaulenco i try check if(splitViewController == nil) it work.